# How can I use `discord.Interaction` commands to check if a bot is in the same voice channel as a user? [Discord Bot | discord.py]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I know theres a lot of similar questions to this, but I am doing it a bit different:

I am utilizing slash commands and passing in a `discord.Interaction` type in like this:

`async def test(discordvariable: discord.Interaction)`

I have a working command that will join a voice channel like this:

```
async def test(discordvariable: discord.Interaction):

     if discordVariable.guild.voice_client is not None:
         await discordVariable.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
     await discordVariable.user.voice.channel.connect()
```

The problem is, it will disconnect and reconnect even if the bot is in the same channel as the user, which I do not want. How can I rewrite this so that it will first check if the bot is in the same channel as the user so it won't disconnect if it is? I want to also add a statement where if its in a different channel, move to the users channel, and if its in no voice channel, connect directly to the users channel (as it currently does).

Answer (score 0):

You've gotten pretty close; `voice_client` is a [`VoiceClient`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceClient) object and has a [`channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.channel) property that we can use to see what channel our bot is in. You have already found how to get the user's channel - so it's a simple matter of checking them. `VoiceClient` also has a [`move_to`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.move_to) method.

```py
async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction):

    user_voice = interaction.user.voice

    if not user_voice:
        # user is not in a voice channel - exit
        await interaction.response.send_message("You are not in a voice channel", ephemeral=True)
        return

    bot_voice = interaction.guild.voice_client

    if bot_voice:
        # we're in a channel already
        if bot_voice.channel.id == user_voice.channel.id:
            # in the same voice channel as the user already
            await interaction.response.send_message("Bot is already in your VC", ephemeral=True)
            return

        # move channels now - we're in VC but not the user's VC
        await bot_voice.move_to(user_voice.channel)
        await interaction.response.send_message("Moved to your channel", ephemeral=True)
        return

    # at this point; the user is in a VC and we're not
    await user_voice.channel.connect()
    await interaction.response.send_message("Joined your channel", ephemeral=True)
```

Now we:

- check that the user is in a voice channel first
- check if *we're* in a voice channel
- do nothing if we're in the same channel as the user
- move to the channel the user is in if they're in a different VC
- finally, join the channel the user is in if we're not in anything